# 2 ListViews in the same activity

Tags: android, xml, listview, onclick

If I have 2 or more listviews in one activity,then how do I use a onclicklistener? I mean How do I know on which one of them the user click?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {


        }
```

The above code is what I used,however when I try to use another listview,I just can't find a way to detect which listview is clicked.

Any ideeas to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the `parent` is the listView from which the itemClick originated. So what you can do is keep a member variable for each ListView and compare the parent to those members to see which list triggered the click.

So here's a simple class with what I mean:

```
public class MyTest extends Activity{
  private ListView list1;
  private ListView list2;

  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);

    list1 = new ListView();
    list2 = new ListView();  //or findViewById if you declared them in your layout
    //the rest of your creation code here
  }

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      if(list1 == parent){
         //handle list1 click
      }else{
        //handle list 2 click
      }

        }

}
```

Comment: member variable? I don't really understand what that means. My listviews are decleared immedialty one after another,not in separate functions. Please show me an ex.

Comment: Whether or not they're declared in separate methods is irrelevant. You just need to keep track of the instances so you can compare them later. I edited my response with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked like a charm,now I feel kinda dumb,cause It's easy but untill now I never head of parents :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do it.

**Implement OnItemClickListener**

```
public class ListViewTest extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
        if(view ==myListView)1{

        }
        if(view ==myListView){

        }
    }
}
```

**Set your own listener**

```
myListView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: click on second listview
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as this:

```
  listView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: click on first listview
     }
  });

  listView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: click on second listview
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple , 
only one list can act as the official list under a ListActivity and this list (and only this list) should have the special list id (@android:list i think) so just set the id of the other list to some other id and set its setOnItemClickListener to do whatever you want. I currently work on an app with 2 listViews and an additional list Fragment.